# I want To map over dictionary and then map the value in dictionary key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-ui

I have Data Set That contains Object and Array in it:

> {React Basic Structures: Array(2)}

**Or**

> {"React Basic Stuructures": [{"Topic": "send_AAFBLrk_f0NHXdU.mp4"}, {"Topic": "send_zHeTppE.mp4"}]}

I want a Drop Down List Which has a Lesson at the top and Topics will be displayed, Bellow

Like :
Lesson 1

> Topic 2
>
> Topic 3
>
> Topic 3

Lesson 2

> Topic 10
>
> Topic 20
>
> Topic 30

I want lie this but mape is not allowed in the mape :

```
                   {Object.entries(LessonList).map(([key, value]) => (
                    <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTitle} key={key} >
                        <ListItemIcon ><FiberManualRecordOutlinedIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={key} />
                    </ListItem>
                    {
                        value.map((v) => (
                            <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTopics} key='Django Learning'>
                                <ListItemIcon ><FiberManualRecordIcon /></ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary='Django Learning' />
                            </ListItem>
                        ))
                    }
                ))}
```

Comment: Please try to format data structure as code instead of as quotes

Comment: can you pls tell me how can I structure it from the Backend is handled by me so I can send it in any format I want but I can't create the scenario

Comment: I meant to say that as it is, I don't understand your data structure by looking at the question...

Comment: Can you pls give me 10 mints sir on live call pls

Comment: Just put some sample data/ example in a https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: Ok i added it pls check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232283/discussion-between-waqas-devolper-and-t-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have an array like you want.

Then we first map out the `lessons` which contains 'title' and 'topics'.
Thereafter we access the `topics` array and map that out inside the parent `map`.

```js
const lessons = [
    {
      title: "Lesson 1",
      topics: [
        "Topic 1",
        "Topic 2",
        "Topic 3"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Lesson 2",
      topics: [
        "Topic 1",
        "Topic 2",
        "Topic 3"
      ]
    }
  ]

//..

<div className="App">
      {lessons.map((lesson) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{lesson.title}</h1>
          {lesson.topics.map((topic: string) => (
            <p>{topic}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
</div>
```

Comment: I cant map it in the map its giving me syntax error

Comment: Can you tell me what the 'syntax error' says?